# Simple way to merge jacoco ec files?

Tags: java, maven, ant, jacoco

I am running several junit code coverage tests using the jacoco gradle plug-in.  At the end of each test, there is an ".ec" file that gets created.  I would like to merge the results of all these ".ec" files into a single ".ec" file.  Is this possible?

After several google searches, it seems that the only possible way is to use the ant task and maven task to do it.  Is there any way to do it using a simple command line?

Maybe something as simple as : java -jar jacocoagent.jar -merge